# Long press and pan gesture in UICollectionView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uicollectionview, uigesturerecognizer

I'm working on a custom calendar downloaded from [GitHub](https://github.com/WenchaoD/FSCalendar). It's a custom view with UICollectionView added in it to show date cells. I'm adding a functionality of dragging over the cells to get multiple date values. For that I've added UILongpressgesture

What I've tried,

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UILongPressGestureRecognizer *dragDateGesture;

 self.dragDateGesture = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleDragBeginDate:)];
 self.dragDateGesture.delegate = self;
 self.dragDateGesture.minimumPressDuration = 0.05;
 [self.collectionView addGestureRecognizer:self.dragDateGesture];

- (BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
return YES;
}
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer{
return YES;
}
- (void)handleDragBeginDate:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
 NSLog(@"Gesture recognised");
}
```

In the above code, I've added long press gesture and setting simultaneous gesture recognizer to yes. I'm not sure, whether adding a long press gesture will call the `handleDragBeginDate` method with UIPanGestureRecognizer getter. I'm new to gesture concept. It's not calling that method while dragging over collectionview.

What might be the issue here? can anyone please guide me on this?

If the way that I'm proceeding is wrong, new suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what you want to do in calendar

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the collection view doesn't have an edit mode similar to what the table view has. Fortunately, [someone has already solved this problem for you](https://github.com/lxcid/LXReorderableCollectionViewFlowLayout).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I've found a custom calendar with drag options, https://github.com/Glow-Inc/GLCalendarView. It's working in simulator. But I can't move those codes to my custom calendar...

Comment: @NAZIK what's preventing you from doing this?

Comment: I'd found the solution, instead of adding UILongPressGestureRecognizer in custom view, I'd added in viewcontroller and added gesture to the collectionview, it's working now, thanks for ur suggestions

Answer (score 1):

`UICollectionView` has its own `panGestureRecognizer` and `pinchGestureRecognizer`. So it's no need to add. I suggest you get touch events in its delegate functions. This is one of these:

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView;
```